Is accessing a global `static` variable from a single TU guaranteed to be safe?
The SFML library initializes an audio device when the first object of type AudioResource is created, and deinitializes it when the last one is destroyed.
I am trying to simplify that code, as I believe that the current solution using std::[shared/weak]_ptr is overkill.
I proposed an alternative using a static global variable. Here's a simplified version (the real one is protected by std::mutex):
// AudioResource.hpp --------------------------------

struct AudioResource
{
     AudioResource();
    ~AudioResource();
    // ...
};

// AudioResource.cpp --------------------------------

#include "AudioResource.hpp"

static int deviceRC = 0;

 AudioResource() { if (deviceRC++ == 0) { /* init device   */ }; }
~AudioResource() { if (--deviceRC == 0) { /* deinit device */ }; }
// ...

I'm think the code above is OK and not subject to static order initialization fiasco, as the deviceRC global static is defined and accessed only in one TU.
My understanding is that -- as long as there are no dependencies between multiple global static variables from different TUs -- there's no risk.
Am I correct, or is it possible that the code above results in undefined behavior by somehow accessing deviceRC before it is initialized?
Is there any scenario where creating AudioResource objects from multiple TUs or when using SFML as a shared library can cause issues?
Is the code safe even if deviceRC does not get constant-initialized? E.g.,
// SomeOtherTU.cpp --------------------------------

static AudioResource audioResource; 
    // Could `deviceRC` be accessed while uninitialized here?


Other SFML maintainers have suggested using a function-scope static variable here:
// AudioResource.cpp --------------------------------

#include "AudioResource.hpp"

static int& deviceRC() 
{
    static int result = 0;
    return result;
}

 AudioResource() { if (deviceRC()++ == 0) { /* init device   */ }; }
~AudioResource() { if (--deviceRC() == 0) { /* deinit device */ }; }
// ...

Is the approach using a fuction-scope static variable safer and/or necessary compared to the one using a file-scope static variable?

Your understanding is correct.  Global variable lifetime has static storage duration.  The local scope static function is not necessary, since the variable is not exposed to other translation units (static initialiization fiasco).  If threading is involved, you may want to use a static std::atomic<int>.  Dave S says "Hi!"

@JaMiT: what would be the issue if deviceRC gets dynamically intialized at run-time? The only place where it can be accessed is from the AudioResource.cpp TU, so I would expect the initialization to take place. Are you thinking of a case where a global AudioResource object is created in a different TU?

Of course the initialization order would only come into play if another translation unit creates a global variable of type AudioResource, or a global variable whose initializer creates an instance of AudioResource.

"the real one is protected by std::mutex" Note that, while static int deviceRC = 0 is statically initialized, a global variable of type std::mutex is in fact dynamically initialized. So you may end up trying to lock a mutex that wasn't initialized yet.

@IgorTandetnik: so one way it could go wrong is if a TU creates a global object of type AudioResource, and the initialization of that global object is executed prior to the initialization of deviceRC (or the mutex in the real case). Right?
Basically: (1) some TU has a static AudioResource audioResource object; (2) the body of AudioResource::AudioResource() is executed prior to deviceRC's initialization; (3) boom -- undefined behavior?

Yes. Well, it cannot happen with deviceRC (it's initialized to 0 as soon as the executable image is loaded, before any code runs); but it can happen with the mutex that AudioResource constructor tries to access. Note that making it a local static in a helper function won't help - that way the contruction would be fine, but the destruction would become a problem; the mutex would be destroyed before the ~AudioResource destructor of that global variable runs (since objects are destroyed in the opposite order of construction).

@IgorTandetnik: thanks. I did not realize the destructor would cause an issue as well. I guess that the only way to guarantee correctness is to stick with the original std::shared_ptr + std::weak_ptr implementation then? Or is there a way to avoid the mutex destruction issue?

@VittorioRomeo I was just ab out to comment on that exact scenerio.  If another TU has a global AudioResource you can't know if deviceRC has already been initialized.

Regarding Is the fuction-scope static variable here safer and/or necessary? The answer is yes.  If it was not static it weould not persist between function calls and you would always get a new int.  You would also have a dangling reference since you a reference to an object that gets destroyed at the end of the funcrion.

@NathanOliver: I understand the implication of making the function-scope variable a static one, I was asking whether the approach using a function would be safer compared to the one using a file-scope static. Clarified the question a bit.

Basically, you need to make your thread safety stuff lock-free, with atomics alone (since you can't guarantee that anything more complex than an atomic would be contructed by the time you need it). I haven't looked at the current approach, but I suspect that's what it boils down to - a lock-free thread-safe initialization.

@IgorTandetnik: would intentionally leaking the mutex be an option? E.g. static auto& getMutex() { static auto* p = new std::mutex{}; return *p; }

I have used the intentional leak approach for an object (such as a std::mutex) that has no resources to clean up other than it's memory footprint.  static auto& getMutex() { static auto* intentional_leak_p = new std::mutex{}; return *intentional_leak_p; }  The memory will be reclaimed by the OS when the program terminates.

Yes, that should work. If you can live with the performance overhead of locking (which depends on how frequently AudioResource objects are created and destroyed).

@IgorTandetnik: I ended up with this solution to prevent destruction of the mutex and still avoid dynamic allocation. If you post your comments as an answer I'll be happy to accept it! Thanks.

What matters is not whether the variable is in a single TU, but how many binaries the TU is linked into.  It's possible to have it defined in multiple dynamic libraries at the same time.

@IgorTandetnik std::mutex has a constexpr default constructor. It will have constant initialization. Only destruction is a concern, depending on what exactly https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.term#3.sentence-3 means.

@user17732522: isn't constinit needed to guarantee constant initialization? Unfortunately I have to target C++17.

@VittorioRomeo No, the rules determining whether or not constant initialization is guaranteed to happen are independent of constinit. consinit only causes a diagnostic if the result is that dynamic initialization would be done.

@user17732522: don't C++11 function-scope static initialization guarantee to prevent the race?

@VittorioRomeo Apologies, I missed the static.

@IgorTandetnik: are you sure about the destruction order issue you mentioned before? I kinda took it for granted, but after some discussion (see https://github.com/SFML/SFML/pull/3089#discussion_r1646608714), it does seem like it's not an issue here. Are we missing something?

Yes, I was wrong. Demo. Somehow the two objects get both constructed and destroyed in the order that works out.

So, you somehow consider shared_ptr to be "overkill", and your solution is to make your own reference counter and spawn a huge discussion about technical details?

@ChristianStieber yes

If deviceRc is statically initialized, the code is safe because:

All static initialization happens before all dynamic initialization.
Static initialization can observe the value stored by some other static initialization only in cases where both occur in the same translation unit; otherwise, trying to read the value of an earlier-declared static variable will fail to be a constant expression, and you won't get static initialization.

If deviceRc is not statically initialized, then you have a problem. audioResource could indeed be initialized before deviceRc, since the two variables are defined in different TUs. When audioResource is being initialized, it's possible that it could see the value deviceRc has prior to dynamic initialization, that is, zero. If deviceRc has dynamic initialization, then presumably the initialization is more complicated than just setting it to zero. So, presumably, the program is not correct if deviceRc's value is read before that dynamic initialization is complete.
The strategy with the function-local static guarantees that result is initialized before it is accessed, and result is destroyed after any static variable that could have accessed result during its own construction. These guarantees will normally ensure that your code doesn't have any initialization or destruction order fiascos, though you can create one if you really try.

Note that this code ended up being unsafe due to this particular use case:
https://github.com/SFML/SFML/issues/3146
